# Flutter Doctor shows problem with GTK 3.0 for CentOS Linux 7 running on Doctor

Tags: linux, flutter, centos7, gtk3

Goal:  Compile and run flutter examples emulating Linux Desktop on CentOS 7 docker container

(Note:  Can't use snapd - not supported within Docker)  Installed manually

Managed to get everything else cleared up but this one:

```
  GTK 3.0 development libraries are required for Linux development.
  They are likely available from your distribution (e.g.: apt install
  libgtk-3-dev)
```

```
The others show OK:
Γú[Γ£ù] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
    ΓÇó clang version 3.4.2 (tags/RELEASE_34/dot2-final)
    ΓÇó cmake3 version 3.17.5
    ΓÇó ninja version 1.10.2
    ΓÇó pkg-config version 0.29.2

Γú[Γ£ô] Connected device (1 available)
    ΓÇó Linux (desktop) ΓÇó linux ΓÇó linux-x64 ΓÇó CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
      4.19.76-linuxkit
```

Another thread had asked for specific versions when diagnosing this.  Here they are:

pkg-config --modversion gtk+-3.0
3.22.30

pkg-config --modversion glib-2.0
2.56.1

pkg-config --modversion gio-2.0
2.56.1

pkg-config --modversion blkid
2.23.0

PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/local/lib/pkg
config:

Would LOVE some help getting this resolved!!!!

Comment: Note to self: [Read carefully](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/linux#additional-linux-requirements), you don't need to install those if you're not building a Linux desktop app.

Answer (score 2):

I updated my Ubuntu to version 22.04 LTS, and when I needed to install Flutter and Android Studio I ran into a similar error in `flutter doctor` output:

```
GTK 3.0 development libraries are required for Linux development.
They are likely available from your distribution (e.g.: apt install libgtk-3-dev)
```

Command `apt install libgtk-3-dev` returned various errors, at first something like:

```
libgtk-3-dev is already the newest version
```

And then i tried to update all packages:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get autoremove
dpkg --get-selections | grep hold
```

None of these commands didn't do anything...

So, i try to remove `libgtk-3-dev`, and after that repeat autoremove and try to install `libgtk-3-dev` again. But now it showed me that it has some unmet dependency (it looks like it depended on some version of `libpcre3` and\or `libpcre3-dev`) and for some reason `apt` refused to install it.

I tried so many ways to remove this damn package, but I could not do it. As far as I understand, initially the problem is that the version of this shitty package (`libpcre3`) that I have has been stretching since Ubuntu 18, and there is both a 32-bit version and x64, and dependencies are crooked in some of them ... Well, or some other problem - maybe something was not deleted during the next update, although it should have been.

In the end, I managed to solve the problem using a graphical shell over apt - `synaptic` (its great stuff, I recommend it to everyone). It's very easy to set up:

```
sudo apt install synaptic
```

After that, I found the amd64 version `libpcre3` in list, marked it for installation and installed it. After that, just install through the console

```
sudo apt install libgtk-3-dev
```

It worked fine, updating all dependencies.

*P.S. First thing I want to note is that Flutter is incredibly crooked shit (only my opinion). If you haven’t started developing on it yet, don’t start, choose something more stable. If it will be possible to use this garbage, then only in five years at best...*

*And secondly, I spent a lot of time searching and solving the problem with the library, which is essentially perl dependencies. Despite the fact that I myself do not use perl at all. Looks like the notorious "Dependency Hell" is already here.*

Answer (score 1):

It appears most of this has to do with pathing, some of the libs have slightly different names (gtk3-devel, libblkid-devel, xz-devel).  Some irritations around cmake3, and getting more current versions of pkg-config, xproto, kbproto, xextproto, and the configuration of said packages.  At least now I have a clean flutter doctor.

Now, on to trying to run it...

Answer (score 0):

I recently reinstalled the OS on my machine, I decided to install and use flutter through FVM. I had many other problems.

```
    [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.5, on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS 5.15.0-41-generic, locale en_US.UTF-8)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
    ! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✗] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
    ✗ clang++ is required for Linux development.
      It is likely available from your distribution (e.g.: apt install clang), or can be downloaded from https://releases.llvm.org/
    ✗ CMake is required for Linux development.
      It is likely available from your distribution (e.g.: apt install cmake), or can be downloaded from https://cmake.org/download/
    ✗ ninja is required for Linux development.
      It is likely available from your distribution (e.g.: apt install ninja-build), or can be downloaded from https://github.com/ninja-build/ninja/releases
    ✗ GTK 3.0 development libraries are required for Linux development.
      They are likely available from your distribution (e.g.: apt install libgtk-3-dev)
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[✓] VS Code
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability
```

**Solutions:**
*clang++*

```
sudo apt-get -y install clang
```

*CMake*
I was trying `sudo snap install cmake`, But it returned an error, this is because the snap review "cmake" was published using classic confinement and therefore can make arbitrary system changes outside the security sandbox that snaps are usually confined to, which can put the system at risk.

It was suggested to me: "If you understand and want to continue, repeat the command including --classic?
To solve it, I just understood and continued

```
sudo snap install cmake --classic
```

*GTK 3.0 development libraries*

```
sudo apt install libgtk-3-dev
```

This solved everything here, it doesn't have an execution order, each dependency is added independently.

I hope I contributed!

Answer (score 0):

I've got the similar problem here, but found a way to solve it.
All library has been installed, but `flutter doctor` says something else.

```
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at google-chrome

[✗] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
    • clang version 15.0.7
    • cmake version 3.17.0
    • ninja version 1.10.0
    • pkg-config version 0.29.2
    ✗ GTK 3.0 development libraries are required for Linux development.
      They are likely available from your distribution (e.g.: apt install libgtk-3-dev)

[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
```

When I check with `pkg-config --list-all |grep gtk` it shows `gtk+-3.0' was there.

```
gtk+-3.0                       GTK+ - GTK+ Graphical UI Library
gtk+-unix-print-3.0            GTK+ - GTK+ Unix print support
gtk+-wayland-3.0               GTK+ - GTK+ Graphical UI Library
gtk+-broadway-3.0              GTK+ - GTK+ Graphical UI Library
gtk+-x11-3.0                   GTK+ - GTK+ Graphical UI Library
```

But when I do `pkg-config --exists 'gtk+-3.0'; echo $?` it always return 1.
It took me a while to figured out pkg-config has additional option `--print-errors` to show what was happen behind the hut when we use `--exists`.

Doing `pkg-config --exists --print-errors 'gtk+-3.0'` in my case it gave me

```
Package wayland-client was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `wayland-client.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
Package 'wayland-client', required by 'gdk-3.0', not found
```

That's how stingy that `flutter doctor` not telling you what was happen behind.

Digging a bit, it turns out that `wayland-client` is part of `wayland-devel` in rpm based distro, I use openSUSE btw. After installing `wayland-devel`, `flutter doctor` says everything's OK.

```
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at google-chrome

[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
    • clang version 15.0.7
    • cmake version 3.17.0
    • ninja version 1.10.0
    • pkg-config version 0.29.2

[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
```

Well, you can hunt down your errors now.

Hope that help.